# Connecting boards in Azure

Tags: azure-boards

I would like to somehow connect boards in Azure Boards.

There are several teams with independant boards.

If one team decides that en Epic needs to be on the backlog of one or more teams, it needs to become visible on the board of one or more teams.

That first process is a seperate board.

The second part I would like to connect, is work items and tasks. If one Epic is divided in several tasks for several teams, I would like to have them related so I can see in what stages they are on the seperate boards so I can determine the completion time of the whole Epic.

Don't know if any of this is possible.

Searched documentation